# Parallax image with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, parallax

I am building the parallax effect for background.
A sample is here:
http://codepen.io/bilalhaidar/pen/zNxOVV?editors=1100

As you can see the `.container` is collapsing because the `.caption` is absolute positioned and the `.parallax` is relative positioned. Hence, the text appears top without taking the effect of `top: 50%` setting on the `.caption` class.

How to make the text appear centered?

When not using Bootstrap classes (container and row) all works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `col-xs-12` div has no height and default Bootstrap style for columns is `position: relative` so your text is relative to div with 0 height (so `top: 50%` doesn't matter in that case).

You can reset styles for that column like this, so your text will be relative to the `parallax` div with `min-height: 400px`:

```
.parallax .col-xs-12 {
  position: static;
}
```

If you want to center it ideally you can add this:

```
.parallax .caption {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/qREBaZ?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks @makshh a lot! I find it working, but can you please illustrate more on what you have done? You reset the divs to be position:static not relative anymore? 10x

Comment: the explanation rocks. Now I fully understand the problem and solution!